# AnkhSVN/TortoiseSVN VS2015 Pre-Build script for auto insert Revision no longer working

Tags: visual-studio-2015, tortoisesvn, ankhsvn, pre-build-event

I have been using AnkhSVN as my subversioning for the last year with no problems at all. I also use a build script which automatically changes the build number in the AssemblyInfo file like so.

- I copied AssemblyInfo.cs and renamed it as AssemblyInfo.Template.
- I then set the Assembly Version like this.
  `[assembly: AssemblyVersion("1.0.0.$WCREV$")]`
- I then set my Pre-Build script to the following.

`“C:\Program Files\TortoiseSVN\bin\subwcrev.exe” “$(SolutionDir).” “$(ProjectDir)Properties\AssemblyInfo.Template” “$(ProjectDir)Properties\AssemblyInfo.cs”`

This has always worked but for some reason I am now getting this error when I build my solution.

`ERROR
The command "“C:\Program Files\TortoiseSVN\bin\subwcrev.exe” “C:\Visual Studio 2015\Projects\AAOEE Report\.” “C:\Visual Studio 2015\Projects\AAOEE Report\AAOEE Report\Properties\AssemblyInfo.Template” “C:\Visual Studio 2015\Projects\AAOEE Report\AAOEE Report\Properties\AssemblyInfo.cs”" exited with code 123.`

Comment: 1. Run it in command-line by hand 2. Exit code 123 does not exit for subwcrev, BTW 3. Plain “$(SolutionDir)” may be OK

Comment: Running via command line does not give me any errors it just gives the usage list

Comment: command-line with **all** the same parameters - usage-list only may be if you provide less than needed data (and call in pre-build *is correct*, only double quotes seems strange)

Comment: @LazyBadger yep I used the same parameters